# How to design tables for a class that contains many classes. (MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql

How would I design tables in MySQL to save states of a class that contains many other classes?

Here is a concrete example from my project requirment.

```
 public class Profile{
      private long userId;
      private String firstName;
      private String lastName;
      private Equipment equipment;
      private TennisRacket tennisRacket;
  }
```

The class is from an Android project. I am using JAX-RS for the backend. I need to save this class in the back end.

The String and long is easy but I don't know how to approach the two objects in this class.

Comment: Look into JPA, which you will probably want to use. You may also need to learn about how foreign keys and joins work in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create three tables (profile,equipment,tennis_racket) and make the relationship with them.

```
create table profile(
   userId INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
   first_name VARCHAR(20) default NULL,
   last_name  VARCHAR(20) default NULL,
   equipment_id     INT  default NULL,
   tennis_racket_id     INT  default NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (userId)
);

create table equipment(
   id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
--other columns your class has 
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create table tennis_racket(
   id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
--other columns your class has 
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

if you use JPA you can use following entity classes 

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "profile")
 public class Profile{
      private long userId;
      private String firstName;
      private String lastName;
      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name="equipment_id", nullable=false)
      private Equipment equipment;
      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name="tennis_racket_id", nullable=false)
      private TennisRacket tennisRacket;
  }

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "equipment")
 public class Equipment {
      private long Id;
        //add other attributes
  }

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "tennis_racket")
 public class TennisRacket{
      private long Id;
    //add other attributes
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The common pattern for this is to have a table called `profile`, and tables for your other objects `equipment` and `tennis_racket`.

In your `profile` table you have a field called `equipment_id` which is a foreign key that references a row in the `equipment` table, and similarly another field called `tennis_racket_id` which is a foreign key that references a row in the `tennis_racket` table.

```
profile
|user_id|first_name|last_name|equipment_id|tennis_racket_id|
|1      |Bob       |Brown    |7           |5               |

equipment
|equipment_id|description|
|7           |ball       |

tennis_racket
|tennis_racket_id|size |
|5               |large|
```

You can manage all of this by yourself and use a `JDBC` connection to query the database, and then populate your objects manually. A query to retrieve the tennis racket for a user with id = 1 might look like this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM profile p
JOIN tennis_racket t ON p.tennis_racket_id = t.id
WHERE p.user_id = 1
```

See how we join the `profile` table to the `tennis_racket` table on the `tennis_racket_id`.

You could use an `ORM` (Object Relational Mapping) tool like [JPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) or [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) to manage the heavy lifting for you. At a basic level it gives you an SQL-like query language to use, and handles copying the results of the query into your Java objects. This is a more complex solution in some ways, you'll have to learn some new tools, but it can be much easier in the long run.

Comment: it seems like it would be better if each tables you created contains the user_id.

Comment: It could be. I tried to mirror your problem statement as closely as possible so it would be easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like each person only has **one** equipment and **one** tennisRacket. So I guess matt's answer is good.

If each person can have many equipments or tennisRacket, you should have one more table which **primary key** is **(user_id,equipment_id,tennis_racket_id)**.